# Will unlink always work?

Tags: php

Say I want to update my script. Say I got a good content already downloaded. I want to delete the old file and replace it with the updated one. However, the file may be executed or something.

How do I make sure I can always replace the file? Should I wait till the file become available, etc?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: are you having problems with unlink not working or is this a "just curious" question?

Comment: If you are updating a file there is no need to unlink it.

Comment: What do you mean? I may rename the file and then it fails.I think I would check if unlink is success. If not, I'll wait for 5 seconds and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) always worked. Besides the obvious of the file not existing.

**Some things to consider :**

If the file exists

Folder permissions

On **Windows** machines where the file is in use so the file does not get removed. The offending process has to be terminated to allow access to the file again.

For the most part [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) will get you where you need to go. In most circumstances, like for updating a script, the script is executed when the page is loaded so the script is in use for that instance and could cause a problem if you happen to unlink right as it is being accessed.

Catching the [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) exception would be key in this process.

Most, if not all problems you run into with file management will be from Windows servers.